# Add less compilation to dotnet new templates

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less, .net-core, single-page-application

following this blog post https://www.hanselman.com/blog/dotnetNewAngularAndDotnetNewReact.aspx I've installed the SPA templates with

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

and created a new react redux app with

```
dotnet new reactredux
```

but now I would like to add less compilation. What should I add to webpack.config.js to be able to do that ?
And what should I add in my react component to be able to reference a less file ?